# gnu-libstdc++ 4.6 can't use std::string on windows using eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, stl, android-ndk

I'm using this version of the stl that is the one that comes with android ndk and I can't use the common std::string. I have include the string header and it is found but std::String is not found. I'm porting my code from another platform and the string class allways has been there. Is this stl version not completed or something?. Navigating through the include folders I have not found any other include that could substitute this one.

Could it be better to use the stl-port distributio that comes with android ndk too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a compile error or an indexing error in eclipse? Post the log if possible.

Comment: Oddly after closing everything, cleaning, and rebuilding it is working now :/. I rebuild the solution several times but did not tried to close and reopen eclipse. Odd... Thanks anyway for your time.